# How to implement bidirectional relationship in SDN 6

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

How should bidirectional relationships be implemented in SDN 6?

I have the following implementation of two entities and a repository

```
@Node("UserAccount")
class UserAccount(

    @Id
    val username: String,

    ) {

    @Relationship(type = "HAS_ACCOUNT")
    var person: Person? = null
}
```

```
@Node("Person")
class Person(

    @Relationship(type = "HAS_ACCOUNT")
    var userAccount: UserAccount? = null,

    ) {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    var personId: Long = -1
}
```

```
@Repository
interface PersonRepository : Neo4jRepository<Person, Long> {
    fun findByPersonId(personId: Long): Optional<Person>
}
```

After fetching person by personId the following exception occurs:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: The node with id 646 has a logical cyclic mapping dependency. Its creation caused the creation of another node that has a reference to this.
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is rooted in the dependency chain (cycle) `Person` -> `UserAccount` -> `Person`, as you have already discovered.
Spring Data Neo4j has a dead-lock detection during mapping to avoid stack overflow / infinite recursion if it comes to cyclic mapping dependencies. This is why you see the exception.

What happens in detail?

1. SDN starts mapping the `Person` that depends on an `UserAccount` instance (constructor) and puts it in a set of "objects in construction".
2. The `UserAccount` instance gets created AND the properties of it populated. This has to be done because a property can -besides public visibility and setter- also be "set" by using a wither method (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping.fundamentals.property-population) and would result in a new (and different instance of the `UserAccount`)
3. The `person` property needs the `Person`-in-construction -> Exception

To avoid this, you can either remove the constructor dependency and define a field.
Another option is to discard the bi-directional relationship definition completely.